# How to run Kong API Gateway using docker containers?

Tags: docker, kong

I am very new to Kong API Gateway, and am currently attempting to run a Kong container with PostgreSQL as my database container.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Start your database:**

```
 $ docker run -d --name kong-database \
                  -p 5432:5432 \
                  -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
                  -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
                  postgres:9.4
```

**2. Start Kong:**

Start a Kong container and link it to your database container, configuring the KONG_DATABASE environment variable with postgres.

```
$ docker run -d --name kong \
              --link kong-database:kong-database \
              -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
              -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
              -p 8000:8000 \
              -p 8443:8443 \
              -p 8001:8001 \
              -p 7946:7946 \
              -p 7946:7946/udp \
              kong
```

**3.Verify Kong is running:**

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8001
```

Comment: Did anybody succeed bringing that into a docker-compose.yml file and solving at the same time the issue that the kong-database is not ready at the time kong wants to connect to the db?

Comment: @StefanWalther i am still looking for the right way to implement above in docker-compose.yml that support stack deployment.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [Kong installation guide](https://getkong.org/install/docker/). It worked for me as expected.

Step 1: Start Postgres container

```
docker run -d --name kong-database \
          -p 5432:5432 \
          -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" \
          -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong" \
          postgres:9.5
```

Step 2: migrate database

```
docker run --rm \
--link kong-database:kong-database \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
kong:latest kong migrations up
```

Step 3: start Kong

```
docker run -d --name kong \
--link kong-database:kong-database \
-e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
-e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
-e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001" \
-e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL=0.0.0.0:8444" \
-p 8000:8000 \
-p 8443:8443 \
-p 8001:8001 \
-p 8444:8444 \
kong:latest
```

Step 4: verify

```
curl -i http://localhost:8001/
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering @StefanWalther's question, here's an example on how to make it work with docker-compose:

```yaml
    version: "2.1"
    services:
      kong:
        image: kong:latest
        depends_on:
          kong-database:
            condition: service_healthy
        healthcheck:
          test:
            - CMD
            - nc
            - -z
            - localhost
            - "8443"
          retries: 10
        links:
          - kong-database:kong-database
        command: 
          - "kong"
          - "start"
          - "--vv"
        environment:
          - KONG_DATABASE=cassandra
          - KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database
          - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001
          - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL=0.0.0.0:8444
          - KONG_NGINX_DAEMON=off
        ports:
          - "443:8443"
          - "8001:8001"
        restart: always
        network_mode: "bridge"
      kong-database:
        image: cassandra:3
        healthcheck:
          test:
            - "CMD-SHELL"
            - "[ \"$$(nodetool statusgossip)\" = \"running\" ]"
          retries: 10
        volumes:
          - ~/kong-database/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
        expose:
          - "9042"
        restart: always
        network_mode: "bridge"
```

And, as an extra, you can add kongfig to reconfigure the instance again:

```yaml
      kong-configurer:
        image: mashupmill/kongfig
        depends_on:
          kong:
            condition: service_healthy
        links:
          - kong:kong
        volumes:
          - /app/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
        command: --path /config.yml --host kong:8001
        network_mode: "bridge"
```

You can dump the configuration to use in this last container with:

```bash
kongfig dump --host localhost:8001 > ~/config.yml
```

More info on Kongfig, [here](https://github.com/mybuilder/kongfig).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the following repo?

https://github.com/Mashape/docker-kong

Answer (score 0):

Here's my own docker compose and it works perfectly(from kong's docker project on github, i used kong-oidc, you can choose whatever version you like).

```html
kong:
    image: kong:1.3.0-alpine-oidc
    container_name: kong
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "kong", "health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # Listener
      - "8001:8001" # Admin API
      - "8443:8443" # Listener  (SSL)
      - "8444:8444" # Admin API (SSL)
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE:         postgres
      KONG_PG_HOST:          kong-db
      KONG_PG_PORT:          5432
      KONG_PG_DATABASE:      api-gw
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG:  /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG:  /dev/stderr
      KONG_PROXY_LISTEN:     0.0.0.0:8000, 0.0.0.0:8443 ssl
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN:     0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl
      KONG_PLUGINS:          bundled,oidc
      KONG_LOG_LEVEL:        debug

  kong-migrations:
    image: kong:1.3.0-alpine-oidc
    command: kong migrations bootstrap
    container_name: kong-migrations
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: api-gw
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD:
      KONG_PG_USER: kong
    links:
      - kong-db:kong-db
    restart: on-failure

  kong-migrations-up:
    image: kong:1.3.0-alpine-oidc
    container_name: kong-migrations-up
    command: kong migrations up && kong migrations finish
    depends_on:
      - kong-db
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: api-gw
      KONG_PG_HOST: kong-db
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD:
      KONG_PG_USER: kong
    links:
      - kong-db:kong-db
    restart: on-failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2020

1. Create bridge network for containers can access each others

```
docker network create my-net
```

2. Start kong-database container

```
docker run -d --name kong-database --network my-net  -p 5432:5432  -e "POSTGRES_USER=kong" -e "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" -e "POSTGRES_DB=kong"  postgres:alpine
```

3. Run temporary container to initialize data for kong-database

```
docker run --rm \
    --network my-net \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
    -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
    kong:latest kong migrations bootstrap
```

4. Run kong container

```
docker run -d --name kong \
    --network my-net \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=postgres" \
    -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
    -e "KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout" \
    -e "KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN_SSL=0.0.0.0:8444" \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -p 8443:8443 \
    -p 8001:8001 \
    -p 8444:8444 \
    kong:latest
```

5. Verify

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8001
```